# Derived class forcing property to be written into initializecomponent

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-forms-designer, codedom

I have a base class and a derived class (described below), and a single property, "TestProperty".  My goal is to get the value I set in testproperty to be serialized inside intializecomponent.  This is very KEY because at a later point, i need the base class to have access to the new value of this property at design-time, and unless that value is set in intializecomponent, I won't have access to this new, "default value" if you well (however, i don't think the defaultvalueattribute is relevant in this case).

In the case below, the only way to get my property to serialize is if I open up "derived" in the designer and manually set the property to a new value.

I'm concerned that a custom codedomserializer is going to be the solution, but i'm very much trying to avoid that.  I want "base" to have as little code as possible.

How can I get my property (set wherever i can get it from, in code) to get jammed into initializecomponent with editing it from the designer?

```
public partial class Base : Form
   {
      public Base()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         TestProperty = "set in the base class";
      }
      [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
      public string TestProperty
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
```

And a simple derived class

```
public partial class Derived : Base
   {
      public Derived()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.TestProperty = "i want to be packed into initializecomponent somehow";
      }
   }
```

Some more information on why I'm trying to do what I am doing.

My problem is this, when I have "derived" open in the designer, i have a custom editorcontrol bieng used to edit some property, called "editableproperty".  EditableProperty needs access to TestProperty in this case.  At runtime, its no problem, I have full access to Derived as a type, and its no problem.

The problem is that the EditorControl i'm using is in a different assembly, and it (for whatever reason, i think its because its in a different assembly than derived), doesn't load the new value i set in the contructor of derived.

Basically, when i open derived in the designer and try to use a custom editor, it gets "set in base class" as the value for TestProperty.   I need to have TestProperty set in initializecomponent in order for my editorcontrol to see the value.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to have that value written directly to InitializeComponent if you are going to set it yourself. You say you won't have access to this new, "default value", but in fact any usage of Derived (including deriving other forms from it) WILL include that value. Maybe if you can explain more about what you are trying to accomplish, it will help me give you a better answer.

Comment: I (poorly) edited the question to hopefully explain what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form designer is not creating an instance of Derived; it is creating an instance of Base, and then calling the InitializeComponent method from Derived. That's why the new value of the property that you are setting is not picked up by the designer.

All you have to do is set the value of the property in the designer for Derived, instead of setting it in the constructor. That will persist the new value of the property in InitializeComponent and make it visible at design time.

Comment: If i could do that I would.  The whole point of the exercise is that I want to do it from code.  The property im trying to set in derived i'm getting from a *.settings file in the project containing derived.

Comment: Well, that is different. With the form selected in the designer, look in the properties window. See the very first line, "(ApplicationSettings)"? You can use that to create a binding between the TestProperty and the setting. If it is not an application setting, you can use the next line, "(DataBindings)", to create a binding (you will have to create an Object data source that references the strongly type class that wraps your settings file).

Comment: I'll give that a try, I'm kind of expecting the following issue though: the base class and my editor class are in an assembly "A", and my settings file is in assembly "B". Will that be an issue?

Comment: Not too sound too noobish, but could you explain "you will have to create an Object data source that references the strongly type class that wraps your settings file" a little bit more?  Thanks a ton

Comment: Actually you can disregard that; the "(ApplicationSettings)" binding will allow you to bind to any Settings file in the project.

Comment: The application settings worked great.  My one stretch that I'm going to try to add is this: I don't want to have to set it in the derived form I create it, I want it to automatically bind to a string i specify.  I'm going to try jamming this into initializecomponent via a codedomserializer.  It shoudl work fine if  I emit exactly what it already puts out.  Thanks for the help.